# How to restrict to call shouldOverrideUrlLoading when first time webview loading in fragment

Tags: android

In my app, there are four tabs and in the second tab, I am trying to load webview...
after disable `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` it perfectly load webview in fragment...
but with `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` method, it redirects on new activity...
But what I want is to load webview first on fragment and after clicking on any content link it should be redirected on new activity

```
 private void setUpWebView() {

    WebSettings ws = webView.getSettings();
    ws.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    ws.setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webView.setScrollContainer(false);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    mContext = context;
}

private class WebViewClient extends android.webkit.WebViewClient{

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(),WebViewShowActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean? having `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` method does not load your `webview` well?

Comment: yes it does.... when i disable this method and after write this method in fragment it redirect in another activity.But i want to load webview in fragment but this method redirect in another activity,...But webview should be load in fragment and than clicking any link it should be redirect to other activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class WebViewJavaScriptInterface {
        public Context context;

        public WebViewJavaScriptInterface(Context context) {
            this.context = context;
        }

        @JavascriptInterface
        public void openPost(String url,String posttitle) {
            String postUrl = "https://google.in"+url;
            String postTitle = posttitle;
            Log.d("POSTURL",postUrl);
            Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), WebViewShowActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("linkUrl",postUrl);
            intent.putExtra("postTitle",postTitle);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        @JavascriptInterface
        public void openVideo(String url) {
            String youtubeUrl = url;
            Log.d("YoutubeURL",youtubeUrl);
            ForTrainertUtil.playPostVideoForYoutubeID(context,youtubeUrl);
        }


    }
```

this is how we can handle click event from web page through JavaScript..
when I click on a specific content of web page it handle associate method in android.

Answer (score 0):

You can check condition

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request)
{
    if (view.getUrl()!=baseUrl) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), WebViewShowActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: yes you are right but i did this diffrently..see i have posted my answer.

Answer (score 0):

To load url in webview you should load it in webview object returned in callback that is "view" and to open clicked links from webview content you should check request and load that in new activity.

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String request) {
                if (request != null && request.toString().startsWith("http://")) { //comparison params is upto your requirements
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, secondactivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    return true;
                }
                return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, request);
            }
        });
```

Comment: yes you are right but i did this diffrently..see i have posted my answer.